# Geoserver CSV - changing the default comma separator

Tags: geoserver, csv, geoserver-rest-api

I would like to know if it is possible to change the default comma separator CSV exportation in Geoserver using semicolon i.e. as a separator.

Some of the tables that I published have large text fields which are filled by users. So, these fields can contain commas as a part of data. Once I want to export a table to a CSV file by a WFS request, I am having unstructured content in some rows.

I had a look to the documentation but I've only found [that](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html) and it seems no useful for my purpose.

Does anybody have any advice to find out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not way to set a different separator, unfortunately. Although Geoserver will quote fields containing commas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

csv file output format_options:

format_option=filename:: if a file name is provided, the name is used as the output file name. For example, format_options=filename:roads.csv.

format_option=csvseparator: (default is `,` ): if a separator is provided, it is used to separate values in output csv file. For example, format_options=csvseparator:- is used to get dash separated file.

Some special characters need to be handled using keywords as below:

space separated: format_options=csvseparator:space

tab separated: format_options=csvseparator:tab

semicolon separated: format_options=csvseparator:semicolon